# Nested autonumbering with jQuery: how to reset after each heading

Tags: jquery, each

I have the following divs;

```
<div class="category">

<div class="title">

<div class="title-number">
</div>

<div class="title-name">
</div

</div>

<div class="sub">

<div class="sub-number">
</div>

<div class="sub-name">
</div

</div>

<div class="sub">

<div class="sub-number">
</div>

<div class="sub-name">
</div

</div>

<div class="sub">

<div class="sub-number">
</div>

<div class="sub-name">
</div

</div>

<div class="title">

<div class="title-number">
</div>

<div class="title-name">
</div

</div>

<div class="sub">

<div class="sub-number">
</div>

<div class="sub-name">
</div

</div>

</div>
```

jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.title-number').each(function (index, value) {
        var num = index + 1;
        $(value).html(num);
    });
});
```

This works fine to number each heading.

What I want to do is be able to number each sub-category as well, such that the above divs would be populated as such;
1.0 (Heading)
1.1 (Sub category)
1.2 (Sub category)
1.3 (Sub category)

2.0 (Heading)
2.1 (Sub category)

And so forth.

I have tried various ways to nest the .each function above, but this doesn't work. If I try to assign the index of the outer loop to a variable, and then use that variable within the inner loop it seems to give me the number of the last title in the list, and therefore all sub heading number begin with 28.1, 28.2, 28.3 and so forth.

I then tried using some standard javascript for loops (not advised) but couldn't get this to work either.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('[class*=number]').length; i++){
    $(".title-number").eq(i).html(i+1);

    for(var j = 0; j < $(".sub-line").length; j++){
    $(".sub-number").eq(j).html(=i+(j/10));
    }
}
```

Somewhere, something went very wrong. Any suggestions would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current html structure does not help you very much. I suggest you also group the titles and corresponding subs into sections.

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="title-number"></div>
            <div class="title-name">Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="sub-number"></div>
            <div class="sub-name">Sub</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="sub-number"></div>
            <div class="sub-name">Sub</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="sub-number"></div>
            <div class="sub-name">Sub</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">
        <div class="title">
            <div class="title-number"></div>
            <div class="title-name">Title</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub">
            <div class="sub-number"></div>
            <div class="sub-name">Sub</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your jQuery can then be:

```
$(function() {
    $('.section').each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('.title-number').html(index + 1);
        $(this).find('.sub-number').each(function(idx) {
            $(this).html((index + 1) + '.' + (idx + 1));
        });
    });
});
```

If you cannot change the html structure then maybe this will work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('.title-number').each(function(index) {
        $(this).html(index + 1);
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.sub').each(function(idx) {
           $(this).find('.sub-number').html((index + 1) + '.' + (idx + 1));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense to operate on the outer structure rather than operate deeper-in and therefore require nested loops.